# Unable to find css "ul#items li:first" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have inherited an Rails app, but am unfamiliar with this particular test environment.  When the cucumber tests are run we get:

```
Scenario: Add only an image to a profile by url                     # features/add_an_image_by_file_url.feature:11
    Given I am logged in as a user "admin"                            # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:19
    And I create a profile for "Joe Blogs"                       # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:1
    And I have a fake image url "http://fake.com/images/profile.jpg" # features/step_definitions/photo_steps.rb:1
    When I follow "New photo"                                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:32
    And I fill in "Url" with "http://fake.com/images/profile.jpg"    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:38
    And I press "Create"                                              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:26
    Then I should see "Photo was successfully uploaded."              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:99
    And I should see "profile.jpg" within first profile item          # features/step_definitions/item_steps.rb:18
      Unable to find css "ul#items li:first" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      (eval):2:in `find'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:13:in `with_scope'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:100:in `/^I should see "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/'
      features/add_an_image_by_file_url.feature:19:in `And I should see "profile.jpg" within first profile item'
```

This come from item_steps:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" within (.*?) profile item$/ do |string, filter|
  Then %Q{I should see "#{string}" within "ul#items li:#{filter}"}
end
```

And web steps concerned:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |text, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    if defined?(Spec::Rails::Matchers)
      page.should have_content(text)
    else
      assert page.has_content?(text)
    end
  end
end
```

The HTML in question look like this:

```
    <ul id='items'>
      <li class='note clearfix'>
        <div class='content'>
          <img src="profile.jpg"/>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

What on Earth is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "what's going on here" is pretty simple:

- cucumber executes each step of the scenario using matched step definition
- everything goes ok, until
- it executes "I should see "profile.jpg" within first profile item"
- during this step, cucumber goes to the matched step definition in item_steps
- that definition in item_steps calls another step definition from web_steps
- this last one checks if the page does really have the given content inside the given scope
- and the check fails...

I suppose, the interesting question is "why it doesn't work". Very similar css selector works fine for me when I used it in my cucumber/capybara scenario.

<s>Are you sure the HTML code is really displayed in the browser? There is no conditions in template or in controller which could prevent it from being displayed? What happens when you change 'ul#items li:first' to something more simple, say just 'ul#items'?</s>

**Update:** the problem is really very simple: profile.jpg IS NOT a text content - it's an "invisible" html code. The only error you have is scenario itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have been tinkering with the web site, moving from CarrierWave to Paperclip due to some weird "cannot covert nil to string" error. Although the test is not passing, the development site is working fine when tickled manually.  I suspect there is something wrong with the way it's configured, but I have not been as diligent with TDD as I should have been.  The error of my ways is now bitting me hard as I find a whole new realm of learning.

Comment: Well, the are 2 possible reasons for the problem you described: (1) capybara doesn't work correctly and (2) your cucumber environment doesn't match your development one in some important aspect. 1st reason should be easy to diagnose, 2nd one should be easy fix.

Comment: Hey again.  Thanks for your help.

Capybara seems to work.  I have the latest gem and it launches Safari with file versions of the site viewable.  The development and testing environments are both on my macbook, and since I am using Rails 3 and bundler this should not be an issue.

Comment: Did you try to simplify "ul#items li:#{filter}" -> "ul#items"?

Comment: Oh, my, it was so obvious! "profile.jpg" is simply not a text content! Sorry, for the verbose discourse instead of a short answer. I updated my answer.

Comment: I agree with Alexis, you can't check for profile.jpg using `page.has_content?`. From Capybara documentation for `has_content?`: "Checks if the page or current node has the given text content, ignoring any HTML tags and normalizing whitespace."

Comment: Damnit!  I have been chasing inherited buggy test code instead of actually coding.  At least I have learnt something about BDD and it's value.  Thank you very much!